# Capture with regexp chain where not matching a word

Tags: c++, regex, qt, capture

I would like to capture the string that is between 2 occurrences of word `SAT` and does not contain `SAT`. I have found this so far, which is not working

```
QLatin1String(".*SAT([^(SAT)]*)SAT.*")
```

I am afraid that `[^(SAT)]*` is not doing what i want, that is finding a string with not the word `SAT`. Or maybe the way i do the capture is not good:

```
QRegExp rx(pat);
int p = 0;
QString cap = QString::null;

if((p = rx.indexIn(str, p)) != -1) 
    cap = rx.cap(1).trimmed();
```

Comment: Unfortunately regexes are all wizardry to me, but hopefully this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/2296458

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one :**

```
(?<=SAT)(.+?)(?=SAT)
```

What it actually does is look behind and forward for `SAT`.

If you want to test per string and use the whole string as the sample, then just use this modified version : `^(?<=SAT)(.+?)(?=SAT)$`

---

Btw, just tried this one out (`SAT([^(SAT)]+)SAT`) and it seems to be working too. Here's a demo : http://regex101.com/r/fJ4gO5

Answer (score 1):

You can use lazy quantifier '?'.

```
(?<=SAT).*?(?=SAT)
```

Basically, you search for SAT, then you search as least symbols as possible until you find second SAT. Thus you will not have SAT in your captured string.

Comment: Lol, you just got me by a few seconds!

Answer (score 0):

I have this one:

first, I capture whole string after first occurrence of `SAT` with this

```
const QString pat = QLatin1String("SAT(.*)");
QRegExp rx(pat);
int p = 0;
QString cap = QString::null;

if((p = rx.indexIn(str, p)) != -1) 
    cap = rx.cap(1).trimmed();
```

then, i look for the position of `SAT` in the result `cap`. And if i can indeed find this `SAT` again, i select the characters in `cap` before `SAT` :

```
QRegExp rxrev(QLatin1String("SAT"));
if((p = rxrev.indexIn(cap, 0)) != -1) 
   cap = cap.mid(0,p);
```

It has advantage that it only uses simplest QRegEx methods and works.